# Hints for $\int\frac{1}{1 + (\log x)^2}\, d(\log x)\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't start with this question please help, how to deal with $d(\log x)$ and $dx$.

> $(19)$
>   $$\int\frac{1}{1 + (\log x)^2}\, d(\log x)\,dx = \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_+c.$$
>   (a) $\frac{\tan^{-1}(\log x)}{x}$
>   (b) $\tan^{-1}(\log x)$
>   (c) $\frac{\tan^{-1}}{x}$
>   (d) $\tan^{-1} x$

Errors included. Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYRMy.png).

Comment: Hint: What is the derivative of log(x)? Use a suitable substitution to compute the integral, I suggest let u = log(x).

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo  but question also include $dx$. u can see question 19: http://schools.aglasem.com/22557

Comment: By "$\log^2 x$, do you mean $(\log x)^2$ or $\log\log x$, or something else? $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy $(\log x)^2$. u can see here question 19:  schools.aglasem.com/22557

Comment: d(logx) = (1/x)dx

Comment: @AyushJaiswal, Reason dx is missing is because d(log(x)) is the differential of the function log(x) , like Noam Dolovich is pointing out. In general, you can have d(g(x)) = g'(x)dx for any given function g(x).

Comment: @LordVader007 this question also include $dx$ along with $d(logx)$, see the question 19 here: schools.aglasem.com/22557

Comment: The extra $dx$ on problem 19 is a typographical error. It makes no sense and should not be there.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise the whole thing is 'trivial'... you have one extra dx so d^2 ( ) = 0. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the other $dx$ term.

Please see the below solution:

$$\int\frac{1}{1 + \log^2 x}\ d(\log x)$$

Let $u = \log x$ so then $du = d(\log x)$

Therefore,

$$\int\frac{1}{1 + u^2}\,du = \arctan(u) + \text{constant}.$$

Substituting back in for $u$ you get:

$$\arctan(\log x) + \text{constant},$$ 
which is the antiderivative/primitive we seek.